# QBE Query By Example. How does it handle OR conditions?

Tags: query

I've been looking at implementing QBE into an application but need more information on how more complex queries work.

How does QBE handle "OR" conditions?  For example when searching a telephone book how would QBE work for a query needing the telephone numbers of "John" **or** "James"?

Comment: Take a look at section 6.6.1 of the following guide http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dbbook/openAccess/thirdEdition/qbe.pdf  (page 8 of the pdf document)